# Count By Subgroup

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like below:

```
      Col1   Col2    Col3   Col4
2018-01-12      A       B      2
2018-01-13      A       B      3
2018-01-14      A       C      5
2018-01-15      B       C      7
2018-01-16      B       D      8
```

How do I count the number of occurrences for combination of Col2 and Col3?

Final Expected Output:

```
      Col1   Col2    Col3   Col4   Count
2018-01-12      A       B      2       2
2018-01-13      A       B      3       2
2018-01-14      A       C      5       1
2018-01-15      B       C      7       1
2018-01-16      B       D      8       1
```

Comment: `library(dplyr); dat %>% group_by(Col2, Col3) %>% mutate(Count=n())`, where `dat` is your data frame.

Comment: thanks, appreciate the help

Comment: If you don't care about the name, there is a simple one-liner: `add_count(df, Col2, Col3)`